# Deleted /var/cache by mistake in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

I deleted by mistake the /var/cache folder in my CentOS server. What problem can it cause?
I read some forums about the problem it can cause to the yum installer but i am not sure

Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, there isn't any important data in `/var/cache`. You need to recreate the directory with correct permission, on my system, it is

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 root     root 4096 Oct  4 14:52 cache/
```

`yum` will lose all downloaded `rpm` packages. If you need to reinstall a package, `yum` has to fetch it from the Internet again.

All services will regenerate their cache when they restart. So, you just need to restart your database/web services and do not need to do anything else.

By the way, you should regular clean your `/var/cache` (but don't delete itself) to free your disk space. You just done it :)